# Parallel processing in R with "parallel" package - unpredictable runtime

Tags: r, parallel-processing, cpu-cores, mclapply

I've been learning to parallelize code in R using the `parallel` package, and specifically, the `mclapply()` function with 14 cores.

Something I noticed, just from a few runs of code, is that repeat calls of `mclapply()` (with the same arguments and same number of cores used) take significantly different lengths of time. For example, the first run took 18s, the next run took 23s, and the next one took 34s when I did them back to back to back (on the same input). So I waited a minute, ran the code again, and it was back down to taking 18s.

Is there some equivalent of "the computer needs a second to cool down" after running the code, which would mean that running separate calls of `mclapply()` back to back might take longer and longer amounts of time, but waiting for a minute or so and then running `mclapply()` again gets it back to normal?

I don't have much experience with parallelizing in R, but this is the only ad-hoc explanation I can think of. It would be very helpful to know if my reasoning checks out, and hear in more detail about why this might be happening. Thanks!

To clarify, my calls are like:

```
RNGkind("L'Ecuyer-CMRG")
set.seed(1)    
x <- mclapply(training_data, simulation, testing_data, mc.cores=14, mc.set.seed = TRUE)
```

Running this twice in a row takes a lot longer the second time for me. Waiting for a minute and then running it again, it becomes fast again.

Comment: The runtime with parallel work in R can be based on a lot of factors, including data-size, since R needs to serialize and transfer the data between processes; if not small, then that's non-trivial. Additionally, you don't say if you are restarting the cluster or if the cluster is persistent through each of your re-application of `mclapply(.)`; if the cluster is persisting, and if the data within each node is non-trivial, then garbage-collection might be a factor. (I'm assuming the host OS is idle otherwise.)

Comment: Thanks for the help, @r2evans - my cluster is persistent through reapplications. If the garbage is collecting, though, wouldn't that mean that my runs a minute later should also be taking longer? When I let it cool down for a minute between function calls, timings go back to normal.

Comment: Garbage-collection is not a predictable event (unless you trigger it manually, which is usually not necessary). I don't know that it's a problem, frankly, but it can be a contributor to inconsistent runtimes, which is why benchmarking tools are often affected by spurious "max" values (for instance, see `bench`'s counting of garbage-collection: https://bench.r-lib.org/)

Comment: Does it make a difference if you trigger the garbage collector, that is calling `gc()`, immediately before your `mclapply()`?  BTW, no, other than garbage collection, there's no such thing as "cool down" needs.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used mcapply but I have used parallel, foreach and pbapply packages. I think the inconsistency lies in the fact that there are small overheads involved in firing workers and in communicating on progress of running tasks in parallel.

Comment: I don't necessarily see how those overheads would change between runs of the same code on the same inputs. Could you clarify?